# How to stop excel to calculate any formulas, calculations, error and background refresh etc. when opening an excel from an email

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file which consist of many sheets with a cube formula connected to a cube in IBM Cognos TM1. when a user opens that file from an email, auto calculation get initiated and instead of number value user sees the error value because they don't have cube access. One way is that each user before opening the file from email just turn off their calculation in an existing excel. However, this method is not practical because each time user can be different.

I have used the following macro as a workbook open event

```
Application.calculation = xlcalculationManual

With Application.ErrorCheckingOptions
    .BackgroundChecking = False
    .EvaluateToError = False
    .TextDate = False
    .NumberAsText = False
    .InconsistentFormula = False
    .OmittedCells = False
    .UnlockedFormulaCells = False
    .ListDataValidation = False
    .EmptyCellReferences = False
End With
```

However, it doesn't seems to me working. Is there any way we can disable all formula to auto calculate when sending the file? even if the user has enabled it but when he/she opens the file calculation should not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Evening,

If you are using the CAFE or PAX Excel add-ins, when logged in, there will be an option on the top right of the toolbar that should state "Convert to Static" or similar. I advise saving a copy of the spreadsheet before you do this as this effectively breaks any TM1 links that exist within the spreadsheet and cannot be reversed. Once you have converted to static you can then save that file as "FileName - Static". When a user then opens this spreadsheet it will not recalculate any TM1 formulas and will just show the values. Make sure you have refreshed the TM1 formulas before converting to static to ensure the values are not out of date.

Using this method, any other Excel formulas will still refresh if the user as auto-refresh enabled.

Let me know if this was of any help.

Thanks,